# Loading spinner disables HTML5 required attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, spinner

I have submit button (bootstrap) where i submit some data from input fields to my PHP query. I have added to this submit button a loading spinner after the button has been clicked by the user. Since i have added the spinner id to the button the HTML attribute for "required" is not longer working. It does not indicate the user a missing information anymore.

Example:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#load").click(function() {
          // disable button
          $(this).prop("disabled", true);
          // add spinner to button
          $(this).html(
              `<i class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mb-1"></i> Loading`
          );
          $("#save").submit();
      });
  });
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="save">     
  <input class="input" name="passwort" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" required> </input>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="load"> Save </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're using backticks to make the spinner HTML. Why not try normal qoutes?

Comment: You mean like this?: "<i class=\"spinner-border spinner-border-sm mb-1\"></i> Loading"

Comment: No, I mean like this: `'<i class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mb-1"></i> Loading'`, otherwize you will get a string error. So not a backtick like this `\`` but a normal quote like this: `'`.

Comment: Sure i tried both ways but it is not solving the problem. It still does not indicate a missing input value.

Comment: It works for me, see: https://jsfiddle.net/8rLxt6eu/

Comment: No, your fiddle is having the exact same problem. Please remove in the button the id. Then you will see the "required" note. At the moment it is not showing that note. That is  my problem.

Comment: Ah, I was working with Firefox, and there it works, but it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: With a slight hiccup I've create a version that also works in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/5th6dj0g/1/

Comment: You'll have to work a bit on the rest, because `this` now refers to the whole form.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be a solution but listen the submit event instead of click as proposed below fits for me better. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should listen the submit event instead of click?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").submit(function(e) {
       // disable button
       $('#load').prop("disabled", true);
       // add spinner to button
       $('#load').html(
          `<i class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mb-1"></i> Loading`
       );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="save">     
  <input class="input" name="passwort" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" required> </input>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="load"> Save </button>
</form>
```